# Derivative of f(x, y, z(x, y))

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

[image]

I have computed the derivatives to be:

- $dw/ds = (-5y+5z)(t) + (-5x-2z)(e^{st}(t))$
- $dw/dt = (-5y+5z)(s) + (-5x-2z)(e^{st}(s)) + (-2y + 5x)(2t)$

I calculated the first answer by evaluating dw/ds for s = -1 and t = 5; subsequently meaning x = -5; y = e^-5; and z = 25

For the second answer I evaluated dw/dt for t = -1 and s = -5; subsequently meaning x = -5; y = e^-5 and z = -1

Is this approach correct? I have used the CHAIN RULE to formulate the two derivatives but 'guessed' as to how I should evaluate them at (-1, 5)

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}
\text{Using: }
\\ u'_s &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial s} 
\\[1ex]
\text{Given:}
\\[1ex]
 x&=st\\ y&=e^{st}\\ z&=t^2
\\[1ex]\text{Substitute:}
\\[1ex]
\therefore w & = -5\,x\,y-2\,y\,z+5\,x\,z
\\[1ex] & = -5\,s\,t\,e^{st}-2\,t^2\,e^{st}+5\,s\,t^3
\\[1ex]\text{Apply Chain Rule}
\\[1ex]
w_s' & = -5\,t\,e^{st}-5\,s\,t^2\,e^{st}-2\,t^3\,e^{st}+5\,t^3
\\[2ex]
\text{Alternatively:}
\\[2ex]
x_s' & = t\\ y_s' &=t\,e^{st}\\ z_s' &= 0
\\\text{Apply the chain rule } & \text{ and then substitute:}
\\[1ex]
w_s' & = -5\,x_s'\,y-5\,x\,y_s'-2\,y_s'\,z-2\,y\,z_s'+5\,x_s'\,z+5\,x\,z_s'
\\[1ex] & = -5\,t\,e^{st} - 5\, s\,t^2\,e^{st} - t^3\,e^{st} - 0 + 5\,t^3 + 0
\\[1ex] & = -5\,t\,e^{st}-5\,s\,t^2\,e^{st}-2\,t^3\,e^{st}+5\,t^3
\\[2ex]\therefore
\frac{\partial w}{\partial s}(-1,5) & =
-150\,e^{-5}+625
\\ & \approx 624{\small .0}
\end{align}$

Likewise for the partial with respect to $t$.